# How can I solve a prototype pollution that happens when I run gulp?

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-sass, gulp-sourcemaps

Im trying to setup a development environment on my new Mac. When I try to run gulp I get a prototype pollution error and some more errors which you can find below.

I have already tried to update my Lodash via NPM but this didn't work. As well as uninstalling Node and NPM and installing it again globally.

```
┌───────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Low           │ Prototype Pollution                                          │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ lodash                                                       │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Patched in    │ >=4.17.5                                                     │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ gulp-replace-task                                            │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ gulp-replace-task > applause > lodash                        │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://npmjs.com/advisories/577                             │
└───────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
┌───────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ High          │ Prototype Pollution                                          │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ lodash                                                       │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Patched in    │ >=4.17.11                                                    │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ gulp-replace-task                                            │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ gulp-replace-task > applause > lodash                        │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://npmjs.com/advisories/782                             │
└───────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
┌───────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ High          │ Prototype Pollution                                          │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ lodash                                                       │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Patched in    │ >=4.17.12                                                    │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ gulp-replace-task                                            │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ gulp-replace-task > applause > lodash                        │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://npmjs.com/advisories/1065                            │
└───────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
┌───────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Low           │ Regular Expression Denial of Service                         │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ braces                                                       │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Patched in    │ >=2.3.1                                                      │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ gulp-watch                                                   │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ gulp-watch > anymatch > micromatch > braces                  │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://npmjs.com/advisories/786                             │
└───────────────┴────────────────────────────────────────

MacBook-Pro-van-Jochem:steilachterover jochem$ gulp app
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/steilachterover/node_modules/require-dir/index.js:93
            if (!require.extensions.hasOwnProperty(ext)) {
                                    ^

[TypeError: require.extensions.hasOwnProperty is not a function
  at requireDir (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/steilachterover/node_modules/require-dir/index.js:93:37)
```